# Can a single sentence have both active and passive voices?

Tags: passive-voice

Can a single sentence have both active and passive voices ?

> Keep everything under 2 pages for now to help readability for me

Am I right to say the part to help... is in passive voice?

Comment: A side question... yes a sentence can have both active and passive.  "The report was begun yesterday, and I finished it today."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *to help* is an infinitive, a non-finite verbal form that doesn't carry voice.  There is no grammatical obstacle to including *active* and *passive* voices in a single sentence, though:

> Three men *seized* me, and I **was carried** to the car.

Answer (score 2):

"to help" is a to-infinitive.  A verb form can be either active or passive, but it can't be both. Passive is a form of to be and past participle. In "to help" you have neither a form of to be nor a past participle.

Infinitive forms active and passive, present and perfect:http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-infinitive

Passive forms:  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/active-and-passive-verbs